# How to install all possible Windows keyboard layouts?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, keyboard-layout

I would like to install all the keyboard layouts that come with Windows on my machine.

Installing them manually from the Text Services and Input Languages would be very lengthy, is there any (semi)automated way to do it?

Tips for Windows XP and/or Windows 7 would be great. Many thanks.

Comment: Find the installer binaries for the layouts, run them with /silent, /unattended or similar. http://unattended.sourceforge.net/installers.php . You say they "come with Windows installed", what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I meant all the input languages that can be installed from the "Text Services and Input Languages" panel in Windows. There's a big list of input languages there that can be added. Not sure where to find binaries for that though, any ideas on how to proceed?